# How to Split a String Up into Individual Characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, lambda, split, array-formulas

Using array formula, how to divide each character into a cell.

```
Input   Output                                              
cat     c   a   t                                       
dog     d   o   g                                       
horse   h   o   r   s   e                               
tiger   t   i   g   e   r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another possible solution.

```
=ArrayFormula(
 Iferror(split(regexreplace(A2:A,
               "(.)","$1❄️"),"❄️"),""))
```

[image]

This formula uses REGEXREPLACE to insert a placeholder character after each character, and it SPLITs by it.

[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`REGEXREPLACE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Answer (score 2):

i think this can be done with a simple MID() formula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MID(A2:A,SEQUENCE(1,MAX(LEN(A2:A))),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Whats wrong here [see this](https://i.imgur.com/yO9HlkE.png)

Comment: my bad i mis-copied a parenthesis. Fixed in Edit. @Osm

Comment: Yeh the old way :) upped

Answer (score 2):

In [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), `\B` is not a word `b`oundary. It matches in between strings, where strings don't contain word boundaries like spaces or hyphen `-`.  Since `SPLIT` doesn't support regex or \b, we need to use regex to add a delimiter.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("cat","\B",""),""))
```

But you can ignore `\B` too and use a empty string:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("cat","",""),""))
```

If you ignore it, Before the `SPLIT`, it'll look like `cat`, whereas with `\B`, it'll look like `cat`. A empty string matches `[\b\B]`.

To use it with a array,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),"",""),""))
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but one problem: if I didn't have , does it work ?

Comment: @Osm What you don't have ice cream? Go buy right now. It won't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

Just change the range `A2:A` with your own.

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(range, delimiter,
 IF(range="",,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(range&"","(?s)(.{1})","$1"&delimiter),"'","''"),delimiter)))
 (A2:A,CHAR(127)))
```

[image]

Using the delete control character "also called DEL or rubout", with the [code 127](https://learn.parallax.com/support/reference/ascii-table-0-127). as a dilimiter in `SPLIT` that joined to every charachter with `REGEXREPLACE`: Replace `"(?s)(.{1})"`, with `"$1"&delimiter`

**Compact form**

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(r, d,
 IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(
               REGEXREPLACE(r&"","(?s)(.{1})","$1"&d),"'","''"),d),""))
 (A2:A,CHAR(127)))
```

[image]

```
r           Range
d           Delimiter Char(127)
(?s)        match the remainder of the pattern with the following 
            effective flags

(.{1})      1st Capturing Group
.           matches any character
{1}         matches the previous token exactly one time
$           asserts position at the end of a line
```

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`REGEXREPLACE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) - [**`CHAR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120)