# How Many Ways are There to Order the Letters of a Word using google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, fact, google-sheets-formula

Determine the number of distinct ways to arrange the letters **for each** word in the range `A1:A18`.

| **Input** | **Desired Output** |
| --- | --- |
| arrangement | 2494800 |
| sequence | 6720 |
| succession | 302400 |
| organization | 29937600 |
| disposition | 1663200 |
| structure | 45360 |
| system | 360 |
| series | 180 |
| grouping | 20160 |
| classification | 1816214400 |
| categorization | 5448643200 |
| codification | 19958400 |
| systematization | 27243216000 |
| disposal | 20160 |
| form | 24 |
| layout | 720 |
| array | 30 |

For example the word **arrangement**

Formula:

```
                   n!
nPr =      -------------------
           (n1! n2! . . . nr!)
```

In the (nPr) permutation equation, place the values retrieved from the term **arrangement**.

```
                   11!
nPr =    ----------------------- 
         (2! 2! 2! 1! 2! 1! 1! )
```

```
    1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 x 7 x 8 x 9 x 10 x 11
=  ---------------------------------------------
   {(1 x 2) (1 x 2) (1 x 2) (1) (1 x 2) (1) (1)}
```

```
nPr of word arrangement = 2494800
```

As a result, the letters in the word **arrangement** may be arranged in 2494800 distinct ways.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236471

Comment: @TheMaster I did't saw that, he choose the word arrangement too!

Answer (score 2):

Using this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(BYROW(QUERY({A2:A}, " Select Col1 Where Col1 <> '' "), LAMBDA(rw,
 LAMBDA(v,
 FACT(LEN(v))/
 PRODUCT(BYROW(
 LAMBDA(s, COUNTIF(s,"="&UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(s))))
 (Iferror(split(regexreplace(v,"(.)","$1​"),"​"),"")), LAMBDA(rg, FACT(rg)))))(rw))),""))
```

[image]

Simplified like this:

```
factorial of (Length of the (Range)) / Product of factorial of each sum of unique letter count
```

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`IFERROR`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`FACT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093412) - [**`LEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081) - [**`PRODUCT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093502) - [**`COUNTIF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) - [**`UNIQUE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198) - [**`TRANSPOSE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`REGEXREPLACE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Answer (score 2):

Factorial can be easily found with `FACT`. Unique letter count is a bit complicated, but once we [split the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852831/how-to-split-a-string-up-into-individual-characters/73853543#73853543), we can use `QUERY` to group by and count. Once count is found, we divide the factorial of `LEN` of string by the product of factorial,  just as [@Osm did in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080267/).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  BYROW(
    A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),
    LAMBDA(
      row,
        FACT(LEN(row))
        /PRODUCT(
          FACT(
            QUERY(
              TRANSPOSE(
                SPLIT(
                  REGEXREPLACE(row,"\B",""),
                "",1)
              ),
             "Select count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1) ''")
            )
         )
     )
  )
)
```